# Beamer - Push title up

Tags: beamer

I'm very new to Beamer, so sorry if this is a very easy question. I want the title of my presentation in the front page to be pushed a bit up, because where it is right now is not very visible due to a picture in the background. How can I do that?

Thank you!

Here's an example code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\title{XXX}

\subtitle{TOPIC 1}

\author{John X}

\institute{ABC}

\date{\null}

\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{picture1}}

\begin{document}
{\usebackgroundtemplate {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{picture}}
    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
    \end{frame}}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick hack: place a space after `\titlepage`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\title{XXX}
\subtitle{TOPIC 1}
\author{John X}
\institute{ABC}
\date{\null}

\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}}

\begin{document}

{
    \usebackgroundtemplate {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}}

    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
    \vspace{4cm}
    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```